# For what $x$ : $2\sqrt{x}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}} \leq 2\sqrt{x+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Hey so while doing exercises this popped up. My idea is to put everything under $\sqrt{x+1}$ and then multiply it by $\sqrt{x+1}$. and then square both sides to get that $x \leq 0$. But this is a very ugly method. The one in the answer is using the fact that $4(x^2+x) \leq (2x+1)^2$ but how in the world am i supposed to come up with that... This is actually the result i come up with at the end. It seems as if they did my method and then reverse it. Any other good ideas to solve it? Not graphically. Is it actually viable to calculate the function of area between the functions and maximize the function? Seems ugly here but in general?

Comment: Square both sides and simplify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2\sqrt x+\dfrac1{\sqrt{x+1}}\le2\sqrt{x+1}$$

As $\sqrt{x+1}\ge0.$

this implies and is implied by

$$2\sqrt{x(x+1)}\le2(x+1)-1$$

Now $\sqrt{x(x+1)}\ge0,$  and $2(x+1)-1\ge2\sqrt{x(x+1)}\ge0$

For $a,b>0;a\le b\iff a^2\le b^2$

Comment: So basically my method just a little bit simpler. Thanks ^^.

Answer (score 3):

Observe: $2(\sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt{x}) = \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}} \geq \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}}$

Comment: IT's not that clear that this is true for x>=0 or i am not seeing something

Comment: You should wear a glass.....

Comment: Pretty funny, +1