# Prove that $2\sqrt{x+1} \ge 2\sqrt{x} + 1/\sqrt{x+1}$ for $x \ge 1$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

[image: how can I prove that the blue line is always less than or equal to the red line when X is greater than or equal to one?]

How can I prove that the blue line is always less than or equal to the red line when X is greater than or equal to one?

This is a crucial algebraic step in a proof by mathematical induction. In order to complete my proof,  I have to show that this is true. How do I do this?

Comment: This https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1507361 is elegant and does not even need the AM-GM inequality.

Answer (score 1):

We need to prove that
$$2(x+1)\geq2\sqrt{x(x+1)}+1$$ or
$$x+x+1\geq2\sqrt{x(x+1)},$$ which is true by AM-GM:
$$\frac{x+(x+1)}{2}\geq\sqrt{x(x+1)}.$$